# pythonでPIG法を使い外挿をしたあとに電場を求めるため内挿をしたがコードがあっているかどうかわからない

Tags: python, spyder

プラズマシミュレーションで電場分布を可視化したいので、PIC法の内挿の部分でE=-∇ϕを使い電場を求めたのですが、私が書いたコードで求めれているのか。また、5個の粒子それぞれの電場分布を表示したいが、１個しか表示されていません。何か情報等でも構いません、教えていただけると幸いです。

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import csv
import threading
import random
import time
from numba import jit  # Better to write at the beginning of the code
import decimal
import math



# 条件設定
delta_L = 1.0
delta = 1.0
n_inter = 0
nx = 1000         #x方向のメッシュの数
ny = 1000       #y方向のメッシュの数
xmin = 0         #xの最小値
xmax = 1000*delta #xの最大値
ymin = 0         #yの最小値
ymax = 1000*delta #yの最大値
n0 = 1e12;       #density in [/m^3]
phi0 = 0;        #reference potential
Te = 1;          #electron temperature in eV
v_drift = 7000;  #ion injection velocity, 7[km/s]
phi_p = -7;      #plate potential



convergence_criterion = 1.0e-5   #前回との差






dx = (xmax - xmin) / (nx - 1)
dy = (ymax - ymin) / (ny - 1)

# 初期状態
phi  = np.zeros((ny, nx))
electrode  = np.zeros((ny, nx))
x  = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
y  = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, ny)



# for SOR method
aa_recta=0.5*(np.cos(np.pi/nx)+np.cos(np.pi/ny)) #
omega_SOR_recta = 2/(1+np.sqrt(1-aa_recta**2)) # 長方形領域に対する最適 
加速パラメータ
print("omega_SOR_rect=",omega_SOR_recta)




T=1 #粒子計算における時間ステップ

# 粒子データを格納するための辞書を初期化
particle_data = {}

# 粒子数
n_particles = 5

# 粒子の座標と名前をランダムに生成して粒子データに追加
for i in range(n_particles):
    a = (random.randint(0, 1000000)) / 1000
    b = (random.randint(0, 1000000)) / 1000
    charge = random.uniform(-1, 1) # 粒子ごとに異なる電荷量を生成(例-1～ 
    1の範囲）
    particle_name = f"Particle_{i}"  # 粒子の名前を設定
    particle_data[particle_name] = {"a": a, "b": b, "charge": charge}  
    # chargeキーを追加し初期化
    
    
    
    
    
# 粒子ごとに計算と結果の保存を行う
for name, data in particle_data.items():
    a = data["a"]
    b = data["b"]
    
    # 粒子ごとの計算
    aa = math.floor(a)
    bb = math.floor(b)
    
    a = math.floor(a * 1000)
    b = math.floor(b * 1000)
    
    aa = aa * 1000
    bb = bb * 1000
    
    a1 = (a - aa)
    a2 = ((aa + 1000) - a)
    b1 = (b - bb) * 1000
    b2 = ((bb + 1000) - b)
    
    HU = b2 * a1
    MU = a2 * b2
    HS = a1 * b1
    MS = a2 * b2
    MEN = HU + HS + MU + MS
    
    HUT = (HU / MEN * T)
    HST = (HS / MEN * T)
    MUT = (MU / MEN * T)
    MST = (HS / MEN * T)
    
    aa = math.floor(aa / 1000)
    bb = math.floor(bb / 1000)
    
    charge = np.zeros((ny, nx))
    
    charge[aa, bb+1] = HUT
    charge[aa, bb] = HST
    charge[aa+1, bb] = MST
    charge[aa+1, bb+1] = MUT
    
    # 粒子の計算結果をデータに保存
    data["charge"] = charge
    
    # 計算結果をファイルに保存
    with open("{}.csv".format(name), "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(charge)
    
# 計算結果の出力（任意の方法で）
for name, data in particle_data.items():
    charge = data["charge"]
    print("Particle Name:", name)
    print("Charge Matrix:")
    print(charge)

    non_zero_elements = charge[charge != 0]
    print("Non-zero Force Elements:")
    print(non_zero_elements)

# 電荷置
eps0 = 1


# 電位計算　外挿
@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_checkered(offset, ph):
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range((i + offset) % 2, ny, 2):
            if i == 0 or i == nx - 1 or j == 0 or j == ny - 1:
               ph[i, j] = 0
            else:
                ph[i, j] = ph[i, j] + omega_SOR_recta * (
                  (ph[i+1, j] + ph[i-1, j] + ph[i, j+1] + ph[i, j-1])/4
                  - ph[i, j] - (dx*dy/(4*eps0))*charge[i, j])



conv_check = []
while delta > convergence_criterion:
      phi_in = phi.copy()
      if n_inter % 50 == 0:
         print("interaction No =", n_inter, "delta=", delta)
         conv_check.append([n_inter, delta])
      calc_checkered(0, phi)  # red group
      calc_checkered(1, phi)  # black group
      delta = np.max(abs(phi - phi_in))
      n_inter += 1
            #red-black-SOR法
      
      
      
# 電場計算　内挿

#@jit(nopython=True)
def calculate_electric_field(ph, delta_L):
    L = ph.shape[0]
    Ex = np.zeros((L, L))
    Ey = np.zeros((L, L))

    for i in range(1, L-1):
        for j in range(1, L-1):
            Ex[i, j] = -(ph[i, j+1] - ph[i, j-1]) / (2 * delta_L)
            Ey[i, j] = -(ph[i+1, j] - ph[i-1, j]) / (2 * delta_L)
    
    return Ex, Ey
    
#@jit(nopython=True)
def calculate_electrostatic_force(particle_data, Ex, Ey, q):
    force = np.zeros((nx, ny, 2 )) # x 方向と y 方向の力を格納するために 
3 次元の行列に
    for data in particle_data.values():
        a = data["a"]
        b = data["b"]
        aa = math.floor(a / 1000)
        bb = math.floor(b / 1000)
        force[aa, bb, 0] = q * Ex[aa, bb] #x方向
        force[aa, bb, 1] = q * Ey[aa, bb] #y方向

    return force

#@jit(nopython=True)
def update_particle_positions(particle_data, force, delta_T):
    for data in particle_data.values():
        a = data["a"]
        b = data["b"]
        aa = math.floor(a / 1000)
        bb = math.floor(b / 1000)
        
        # 粒子ごとの位置更新
        a_new = a + force[aa, bb, 0] * delta_T # x 方向の力を考慮
        b_new = b + force[aa, bb, 1] * delta_T # y 方向の力を考慮
        
        data["a"] = a_new
        data["b"] = b_new
        
        
        
# 電場計算
Ex, Ey = calculate_electric_field(phi, delta_L)

# クーロン定数
q = 1.602176634e-19

# 静電気力計算
force = np.zeros((nx, ny, 2)) #x,y,次元

# 粒子の位置に対応するように静電気力を格納
for data in particle_data.values():
    a = data["a"]
    b = data["b"]
    aa = math.floor(a / 1000)
    bb = math.floor(b / 1000)
    
    for i in range(data["charge"].shape[0]):
        for j in range(data["charge"].shape[1]):
            force[aa + i, bb + j, 0] = q * data["charge"][i, j] * Ex[aa 
                                       + i, bb + j]  # x 方向の力
            force[aa + i, bb + j, 1] = q * data["charge"][i, j] * Ey[aa 
                                       + i, bb + j]  # y 方向の力
            
            
            
# 粒子の位置更新
delta_T = 1  # 時間ステップ
update_particle_positions(particle_data, force, delta_T)

# 電場の計算結果をファイルに保存
with open('electric_field.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(Ey)
    
# 静電気力の計算結果をファイルに保存
with open('electrostatic_force.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(force)
    
print("Force Matrix:")
print(force)

non_zero_elements = force[force != 0]
print("Non-zero Force Elements:")
print(non_zero_elements)



# ファイルを書き込みモードでオープン
body = (phi)
header = ('Electrical potential of 2D array')
with open('Deni1.csv', 'w') as f:

  writer = csv.writer(f)  # writerオブジェクトを作成
  writer.writerows(header) # ヘッダーを書き込む
  writer.writerows(body)  # 内容を書き込む
  
  
  
body2 = (x)
header2 = ('Value1 of axis')
with open('jikunoatai1.csv', 'w') as f1:
  writer = csv.writer(f1)
  writer.writerow(header2)
  writer.writerow(body2)
  
  
  
  
  
def plot2D(x, y, phi):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 7), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    X, Y = np.meshgrid (x , y)
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, phi[:], rstride=1, cstride=1, 
cmap=cm.viridis,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    ax.view_init(30, 225)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('phi')

plot2D(x, y, phi)
plt.show()

for particle_name, particle_info in particle_data.items():
    print(f"{particle_name}: Position ({particle_info['a']}, 
          {particle_info['b']}), Charge {particle_info['charge']}")

# 粒子の座標と名前を取得
particle_positions = [(particle_info['a'], particle_info['b'], 
                     particle_name) for particle_name, particle_info in 
                     particle_data.items()]

# グラフの作成
for x, y, name in particle_positions:
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', label=name)

# グラフに名前を表示
for x, y, name in particle_positions:
    plt.text(x, y, name, fontsize=8, ha='right', va='bottom')

plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('b')
plt.title('Particle Positions')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()



#オブジェクトを生成
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,7), dpi=100)
fig

xmin = 0
xmax = 1000
ymin = 0
ymax = 1000

x  = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
y  = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, ny)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.contourf(X, Y, phi, alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.viridis)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')



#電位計算
print("Keisan V")
for i in range(1,6):
    print("x=",i*delta_L,"V=",phi[500+i,500]- 
          phi[500+int(1/delta_L),500])



#電場計算
L = 999
Ey = np.zeros([L,L])
for i in range(L):
    for j in range(L):
        Ey[i,j] = -(phi[i+1,j]-phi[i-1,j])/2/delta_L
print("Keisan E")
for i in range(1,6):
    print("x=",i*delta_L,"E=",Ey[500+i,500])コードをここに入力
```